# Best practice for printing directly to network label / receipt printer from local server

Tags: node.js, printing, network-programming, barcode

I have a web-based application (primarily used on tablets), running on a local server on the network. I would like to be able to print to Network/IP (WiFi or Ethernet) label printers. (Would be a similar method as used by some receipt printers.) Essentially just some basic text and a barcode.

I've been looking at Zebra label printers (such as their ZQ630 models), which are WiFi connected, and can be addressed directly via ZPL format. It appears that you setup a label template using their ZebraDesigner software, load that on the printer, and then can send data to the printer to be used within that template.

However, I'm basically starting from square one with this, and would like any suggestions / feedback from others who have done something similar. The application is using NodeJS as the backend. (React on the frontend.) I'd like to have the client browser send a command to the server, and then the server send the label printer the content to print. (Because it could be used on Windows / Android / iOS, I don't want printer drivers required on the client side.)

Essentially, if I generate the following ZPL:

```
^XA

^FX Top section
^CF0,60
^FO100,30^FDAmazing^FS
^CF0,30
^FO100,100^FDManufacturing^FS
^FO50,150^GB700,3,3^FS

^FX Section with barcode
^BY5,2,150
^FO100,170^BC^FD12345678^FS

^XZ
```

(preview: http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=2&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EFX%20Top%20section%0A%5ECF0%2C60%0A%5EFO100%2C30%5EFDAmazing%5EFS%0A%5ECF0%2C30%0A%5EFO100%2C100%5EFDManufacturing%5EFS%0A%5EFO50%2C150%5EGB700%2C3%2C3%5EFS%0A%0A%5EFX%20Section%20with%20barcode%0A%5EBY5%2C2%2C150%0A%5EFO100%2C170%5EBC%5EFD12345678%5EFS%0A%0A%5EXZ)

And my printer IP is 10.10.10.10, how can I send that data to the printer from the server and make it print that out?

I came across this package, trying to figure out if it would help me:
https://github.com/mrothenbuecher/zpl-rest

If anyone has done something like this on NodeJS and could share some tips or code, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My work-around was to install the label printers (in my case LP2844) on the server as RAW devices.
These were older parallel port devices (I think a few were USB), so I had to install them on the local workstation and then share the printer on the network so I could add it to the server.   It worked pretty well for a small environment and a single server, but I imagine it could get problematic at scale.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but yeah, that's not really a route I want to take when developing a system from scratch.